# Нужно ли использовать android:filterTouchesWhenObscured?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть рекомендация - что нужно использоваться в разметке параметр android:filterTouchesWhenObscured = true
Это увеличивает безопасность приложения и например, приложение которое поверх нашего приложение не может перехватить касание нашего приложения.

На сколько часто этот параметр используется в приложениях и нужно ли его использовать ?